# How to use a variable instead of file to let any command write to?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using `curl --cookie-jar <filename>` to save cookie temperley and load it later in a script.

In OS X, there's no /dev/shm and I don't want too many temp files write to SSD.

Is it possible use a variable instead of a file to let this/any command write to?

A variable can be read like a file with `curl --cookie <(echo "$variable")`, is it involved with disk access?

Comment: Something like that could be buillt with some effort, filling the variable with the -v output of curl (would require you to split http header and data, grepping the cookie value out and adding it to the variable) and using it by passing the cookies with -b back into curl

Comment: Or better, use -c - to get the cookies to stdout and get that into the variable like in @py9's answer, so you can omit the -v and parsing the http header. But I don't know if it will also read it back from stdin, the man page is only says it "wirtes it out", you might still need the -b to set the cookies

Comment: You might want to research (or ask) how to create a RAM disk to use in place of /dev/shm.

Comment: In terms of what you're literally asking for -- shell variables can't be accessed via the `open()` family of syscalls. You can potentially set up a FIFO that's read and written by a piece of running software, but that's as close as you can come. Much better to create a ramdisk to use in place of `/dev/shm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Literal Question

In the completely generic sense: You can't. Shell variables don't have independent existence on the filesystem any more than Python variables or C programs' variables do. (*Environment* variables are exposed to be read by processes, but changes aren't propagated back to parent processes, so even if an operating system had extensions that provided environment variables to be accessible via a filesystem interface -- akin to `/proc/self/environ` on Linux -- that's not helpful here, where two-way communication is needed).

#### MacOS Workaround

You can use `hdiutil` and `diskutil` to create a ramdisk with a filesystem on it to serve the same purpose as `/dev/shm`. See ie. https://gist.github.com/rxin/5085564

#### Alternate Approach: FIFO Abuse

One fugly-but-feasible approach is to use a background process pumping data between a pair of FIFOs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# These are the only two operations that touch disk
mkfifo cookie-write.fifo || exit
mkfifo cookie-read.fifo  || exit

# Start a background process that pumps data from the read FIFO to the write FIFO
datapump() {
  while IFS= read -r -d '' content <cookie-write.fifo || [[ $content ]]; do
    printf '%s\0' "$content" >cookie-read.fifo
  done
}
datapump & datapump_pid=$!

# run an initial curl with cookies written to cookie-write.fifo
curl -c cookie-write.fifo http://example.com/login
cookies=$(<cookie-read.fifo)   # read cookies set by login process

# write back from the shell variable to the FIFO to allow read by another curl
printf '%s\0' "$cookies" >cookie-write.fifo
# read in in that new curl process, write back to the FIFO again
curl -b cookie-read.fifo -c cookie-write.fifo http://example.com/do-something
cookies=$(<cookie-read.fifo)  # read cookies as updated by do-something process
```

This kind of approach requires a great deal of care to avoid deadlocks: Note that the coprocess first reads and then writes; if either of those operations doesn't take place, then it's going to hang indefinitely. (Thus, if your `curl` operation *doesn't write* any cookies, the pump process won't switch modes over from reading to writing, and a subsequent attempt to read the cookie state may hang).

Comment: The script seems work well with sites have cookies(e.g. stackoverflow.com). But if a site dose not send cookies(e.g. example.com) it hangs on `cookies=$(<cookie-read.fifo)   # read cookies set by login process`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yup, that caveat is explicitly described in the answer as originally written -- see the last sentence. Might be able to do something like send a signal to the subshell running the pump and having it switch modes (USR1 for read-next, USR2 for write-next or such), but that's a fiddly enough change and requires enough effort and testing to make it deserve its own question.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse!

Your usage:

```
curl something.com > file
```

Storing in a variable:

```
variable=$(curl something.com)
```

Note that this is not recommended for larger outputs (unless you introduce parsing/regex matching/whatever).

Comment: That doesn't really work for the cookie jar, inasmuch as it should be read and updated independent of the content actually being retrieved.

Comment: That is to say, if one runs `login_result=$(curl --cookie-jar="$tempfile" https://example.com/login)`, one needs **both** the stdout (with the actual content retrieved) and the cookies in two separate stores (so the cookies can be passed into future `curl` invocations -- where it'll again be looking for them to be provided as a filename).