# Redirect output parameter of command to variable using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Hello

I developed a program where one can use flags to output different kinds of data to different files, for example:

```sh
$ ./program -csv file.csv -log file.log -out out.txt -result result.txt ...
```

In this case, the *csv* output should be saved on file `file.csv`, the log to `file.log` and so on. I want a way to save the output directly to a *bash* variable so I can use it later on the script. Example:

```sh
$ ./program -csv $(write to csv_var) \
    -log $(write to log_var) \
    -out $(write to out_var) \
    -result $(write to result_var) \
    ...
```

As a result, I want to see the *csv* output of the program when I call `echo ${csv_var}`. The same should happen to `log_var`, `out_var`, `result_var`, etc. How can I do something like this?

I thought about manually creating a temporary file to each variable, saving the output to the file and reading it back, but I'm looking for something cleaner as in the example above (imagine a lot of instances of the program running in parallel, some files may override others). Also, it is important that the variable data only exists while the script is running, in the "solution" above, if I kill the script, the temporary files / folders would continue to exist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *imagine a lot of instances of the program running in parallel, some files may override others* Create a temporary directory for each running instance of the program and then create files with fixed names inside the temp dir.

Comment: @Leon it won't fully solve the problem, but will make the overriding happen less often. It is important that the variable data only exists while the script is running. I will update the question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572002/how-to-use-a-variable-instead-of-file-to-let-any-command-write-to

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk this seems interesting but does it work when two or more processes are using the same fifo? Thanks

Comment: @Marco My impression is that you don't know about [`mktemp`](https://www.mktemp.org/manual.html) and [bash traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).

Comment: @Leon I do know about `mktemp`, but I'd like to avoid writing to the disk and reading it back. I also do know about bash traps, but they won't work if the script is killed by certain methods.